# Symfony 3 Remember Me cookie

Tags: php, symfony, cookies

I am trying to authorize the user directly in my symfony 3 application, like:

```
$token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'user_db_provider', $user->getRoles());
$userProvider = new EntityUserProvider($this->getDoctrine(), User::class);
$rememberMeService = new TokenBasedRememberMeServices([$userProvider],$this->getParameter('secret'),'user_db_provider', [
    'path' => '/',
    'name' => 'AUTH_TOKEN',
    'domain' => null,
    'secure' => false,
    'httponly' => true,
    'lifetime' => 1209600, // 14 days
    'always_remember_me' => true,
    'remember_me_parameter' => '_remember_me'
]);
$response = new Response();
$rememberMeService->loginSuccess($request, $response, $token);
$this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
$response->sendHeaders();
```

Symfony debug: security.DEBUG: Remember-me cookie detected. But all the time I receive an error: "security.DEBUG: Remember-Me authentication failed, The cookie's hash is invalid". Whats wrong?